# How to force a RibbonButton to be alway enabled?

Tags: .net, wpf, ribbon, commandbinding

I have a Microsoft Ribbonbar inside a Window, and every RibbonButton is associated to a specific command like this:

```
<ribbon:Ribbon x:Key="MyToolbar"  Name="MyToolbar"  >         
<ribbon:RibbonTab Header="File" >
<ribbon:RibbonGroup Header="File"  >
<ribbon:RibbonButton Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.New}"  LargeImageSource="Images/GenericDocument.png" Label="Nuovo" />
<ribbon:RibbonButton Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Open}" SmallImageSource="Images/OpenFolder.png" Label="Apri"  />
</ribbon:RibbonGroup>
</ribbon:RibbonTab>
</ribbon:Ribbon>
```

I'm handling the commands in this way **into the code-behind of a specific Canvas object placed in the same window**:

```
private void BindApplicationCommands()
{
// FILE group
this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.New, New_Executed));
this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Open, Open_Executed,Open_Enabled));
}
```

When I click **outside** the Canvas component where the handling code is placed, all the buttons inside the Ribbon become to be **disabled**.
This is an undesired behaviour, since i want that some **specific buttons** (like the "New" and "Open" commands) are **always and globally enabled**, despite to where i click.
How can I achieve this ?
Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved my own problem.
Since the CommandBindings where defined inside the Canvas component, they weren't manageable into a wider (global) context, so i moved them into the Window code-behind to delegate their execution/activation in a more flexible way.
That's all :)

Comment: Even though you were the one to answer the question you should still mark this as the answer.

Comment: I will when the system allows me to to that. There's a limit of 2 days-wait (for my profile) before I can do it.